# Database insertion problem with foreign key

Tags: php, database

I want to learn to create my own form and by sample I made a form. In database (company) I have 3 tables, employee (employee_id, name, address, birthdate), bill_rates(bill_id, bill) and lastly project (project_name, start_date).

A project has an employee one or more. and the bills is also connected to project.

Do I have to put bill_id and employee_id in project as foreign keys?

Here is my database.

[image: employee table]

[image: bill_rates]

[image: project]

What I did. I make bill_id and employee_id foreign keys to the project table.

In my form I tried to insert from database. the log says successfully in url but in database it only inserts in employee table and billrates but nothing in project table.

Here is a screenshot of my form and the process.php

[image: Company]

and this is my code for the process in inserting the datas

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    include_once 'dbConnect.php';
    //employees
    $employee_id =  mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['employee_id']);
    $project_id =   $_POST['project_id'];
    $bill_id = $_POST['bill_id'];
    $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['name']);
    $address = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['address']);
    $birthdate = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['birthdate']);
    //project employee_id, bill_id
    $project_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['project_name']);
    $start_date = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['start_date']);
    //bill
    $bill = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['bill']);

    if(empty($name) || empty($address) || empty($birthdate) || empty($project_name) || empty($start_date)  || empty($bill) ){
        header("Location: index.php?register=empty");
        exit();
    }else{
        //to the DB we gow
        $sql = "INSERT INTO employee (name, address, birthdate) VALUES ('$name','$address','$birthdate');";
        mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
        $sql2 = "INSERT INTO project (`project_name`, `start_date`) VALUES ('$project_name','$start_date');";
        mysqli_query($conn,$sql2);
        $sql3 = "INSERT INTO billing_rates (bill) VALUES ('$bill');";
        mysqli_query($conn,$sql3);
        echo '<p class="text-danger">'.'Success!'.'</p>';
        header("Location: index.php?register=success");
    }

}


?>
```

I want to determine what query to use because I think I my approach is wrong.

Comment: it is best to show the complete structure of your tables. In a terminal, `show create table project` ... instead of pics (am assuming you are using mysql)

Comment: yes sir i am using phpmyadmin sir. should i type these in the console down below? thank you so much for replying